Locked out of AWS LightSail instance because of SSH daemon issue
I have this Ubuntu Linux LightSail instance that I use for a web application. It's got only the bare minimum software installed for the web application to function that includes Apache (with PHP 8), MySQL, and Redis. It has also got a SSH server like any other default and standard Ubuntu LightSail instance.
The issue is, the web server had started acting up, and I was trying to understand what the issue was. I decided to give the entire OS a reboot. After the reboot, all my access through SSH is lost and I am locked out of the box.
Some useful info:

Both IPv4 and IPv6 have TCP ports 22, 80, and 443 allowed.
I have also used the Connect using SSH option to no avail.
My friend with access to the AWS account says he may have messed with some networking settings on the account, but nothing related to the LightSail service.
The web application is accessible through port 443, but the other two ports do not respond at all.
I tried creating a Snapshot, then creating a new instance out of the Snapshot. The same behavior exists on the newly-created Snapshot.
Weirdly enough, I created an instance out of this old Snapshot (4 months old) that I had, and again, ports 80 and 22 are non-responsive.
I tried creating a new Ubuntu instance and went for detaching the storage on this instance, hoping to attach it to this new instance for recovery. I couldn't detach the primary disk from the original instance (even after completely stopping it).

Any help towards getting my access to the instance or accessing the disk in some other way is greatly appreciated.
